# java mysql input NULL

Tags: java, mysql, insert, null

I am using MySQL Server 5.6, Tomcat 8.0. I can create an SQL input statement that is successful in putting hard coded values into my table but if I try to use a variable instead, it appears as NULL in the table. I have println statements immediately before the SQL statement that show the right value in the variable. My syntax looks right and, as I said, it works for hard coded values.
Please excuse the code formatting. This is supposed to be a quick (HA!) and dirty proof of concept.

Code snippet:

```
// method to update spice table with input data
  public void update()
  {
    System.out.println("Starting Update");
   java.sql.Date useDate = new java.sql.Date(convert(date));

   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   String sql;
       try{
    System.out.println("Starting try...");
      // Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      // Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
      System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

      // Execute update
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      System.out.println("Name is " + name +".");
      System.out.println("Name is " + getName() +".");
      sql = "INSERT INTO spices VALUES (name, 'location', 'container', 'status', useDate)";
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

      // Clean-up environment
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
    System.out.println("errors for JDBC");
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
    System.out.println("errors for Class.forName");
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
    System.out.println("SQLException - stmt.close()");
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
    System.out.println("SQLException - conn.close()");
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
  }
```

server log showing println output:

```
2015-05-25 19:37:46 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
Starting Update
Starting try...
Connecting to database...
Connected database successfully...
Creating statement...
Name is chilli.
Name is chilli.
Goodbye!
```

Table output:

```
| NULL      | location  | container | status  | NULL       |
```

The first NULL should say "chilli".
Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm tearing hair here!
kwl

Comment: Shouldn't it be: sql = "INSERT .... '" + name + "'....'" + useDate + "')" 
with your variables outside the string

Comment: share the code from where u printing "2015-05-25 19:37:46 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized" line.

Comment: Arin, Tomcat writes that when starting up the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
sql = "INSERT INTO spices VALUES ('"+name+"', 'location', 'container', 'status', '"+useDate+"')";
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Comment: Many thanks, Stan. Exactly the help I needed - think I'd spent too much time yesterday dealing with SQL directly. You should have heard the howl when I realised what I'd done.....